# how to parse string having functions and parameter, String is defined in well defined set of "("

Tags: java

My String is

```
String s="(decode(W_Employee_D_3.Fst_Name,NULL,"
        + "decode(W_Employee_D_3.Last_Name,NULL,"
        + "decode(W_Employee_D_3.Mid_Name,NULL,'emptyString','midnamevailable'),'lastnameavil'),"
        + "concat(CONCAT ( concat(W_Employee_D_3.last_Name, ' ,'),"
        + "W_Employee_D_3.Fst_Name ),W_Employee_D_3.Mid_Name)))";
```

I need to write some generalize logic which gives fun1=decode, fun2=decode, fun3=decode,fun4=concat,fun5=Concat,fun6=Concat and their respective parameter1, para2, para3 in any type of collection in Java.
Parameter are those which is passed in function, 
for example 
concat(W_Employee_D_3.last_Name, ' ,')
concat is function and parameters are W_Employee_D_3.last_Name & ','.

String can contains any number of function,parameter and can have different function also.

Comment: What is `fun1, fun2, fun3` or `parameter1, para2, para3` ? Some data? What have you tried so far?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what are the all possible value of fun? are they only decode or concat or there may be other values?

Comment: Please check edited part. In this string decode and Concat are values of fun. In other cases it can be any kind of oracle Sql function. I would like to solve this hierarchy of functions. if it is direct function then i am able to read easily but if it is sub-functions (function inside function) i am not able to read.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a mean kind of task. Maybe you must some ANTLR grammar?
I'll just offer an approach to the less tedious part of the work.

For such kind of nesting one would either

- Parse from left to right using a stack, or
- Use reducible expressions starting with the inner most found redexes, and building some result.

I use the latter, with a map to hold resulting structures, replaced in the string by some "variable."

We could introduce variables for

- a string literal, as that could contain comma, parenthesis and other not to be parsed text,
- a function call

If give a solution for a simplified case:

```
String s = "a(b(c),d(e),f,g(h(),i)";

// Variables are like "§0013" (4 digits)
Map<String, String> variables;
int maxVar = 0;

String expr = "(\\w+|§\\d{4})"; // Either simple term or var name.
Pattern callRedex = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\((" + expr + "(," + expr + ")*)?\\)");
boolean reduced;
do {
    reduced = false;
    Matcher m = callRedex.matcher(s);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        String value = m.group();
        String var = String.format("§%04d", maxVar++);
        variables.put(var, value);
        m.appendReplacement(sb, var);
        reduced = true;
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    s = sb.toString();
} while (reduced);
```

Now one has the function calls as variables. Their value contain variable names, and have again to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks Joop, I will try using ANTLR grammer to parse.